# WiFi Direct on Android not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, wifi-direct

I am trying to develop an app using wifi direct in android Jelly Bean 4.1.1. If p2p is enabled I immedialtely call

```
mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, actionListener);
```

After that I am getting a call back to the

```
onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList)
```

I am testing with 2 Samsung(Google) Nexus device and wifi direct is turned on on both. But this call back is returning an empty list of peers. But for instance if I click on the **Search Peers** button on the default wifi direct interface immedialtely the second device fires the

> WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION

and this inturn calls

```
onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers)
```

as I am requesting for peers for that event using

```
mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, WifiDirectService.this);
```

This time I will be able to see the peers. I am seeing this for a number of times.

What could be the possible reason?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Discovering peermethod:

```
manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
        ...
    }
});
```

If the discovery process succeeds and detects peers, the system broadcasts the WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION intent, which you can listen for in a broadcast receiver to obtain a list of peers. When your application receives the WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION intent, you can request a list of the discovered peers with requestPeers().

For the full example, please check: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html#discovering

Comment: What are you doing then on success ?

Comment: Please, read this tutorial from the Android official website, maybe you are doing something wrong, the example is really easy to understand. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html#discovering

Comment: I am stuck on similar problem now but I can't obtain the list of peers at all. I call 'discoverPeers(..)' on ' WifiP2pManager' instance and I print some message to the log 'onSuccess()' and 'onFailure()'. He always successfully detects peers but it seems like system is not broadcasting the 'WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION'. I do register the broadcast receiver and I do call 'requestPeers(..)'.

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Comment: @CommonsWare can help with any solution ?