# Android Wifi Direct detects peers but Peer List is empty

Tags: java, android, wifi, p2p

Everything works fine but when `WifiP2pManager` calls `onPeersAvailable` method (it calls it correctly) the Peers Device List is empty, which makes no sense because if the method is called, it's because a peer was discovered. :S

Is something wrong in my code? Thanks.

Main Activity, Broadcast Receiver, and Discovery:

```
public class Main extends Activity{

FileManager flManager;
Context ctx;
LinearLayout lay_found_users;
LinearLayout lay_conversations;
AddLayoutItem addLayoutItem = new AddLayoutItem();
private final String TAG = "Main";

//Wifi Direct
WifiP2pManager mManager;
WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener mPeerListListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_main);
    ctx = getApplicationContext();
    flManager = new FileManager(ctx);

    //Wifi Direct
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

    mPeerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList){
            Log.i(TAG, "Peers available");
            int size = peerList.getDeviceList().size();
            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(size));

        }
    };

    mReceiver = new WDBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this, mPeerListListener);
    WDDiscovery wdDiscovery = new WDDiscovery(mManager, mChannel);
    wdDiscovery.discover();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

public class WDBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private WifiP2pManager mManager;
private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
private Main mActivity;
private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener mPeerListListener;

public WDBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel channel, Main activity, WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener){
    super();
    this.mManager = manager;
    this.mChannel = channel;
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.mPeerListListener = peerListListener;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){

        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);

        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED){
            Log.i(TAG, "Wifi P2P Enabled");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Wifi P2P Disabled");
        }

    }else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
        if (mManager != null){
            mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, mPeerListListener);
            Log.i(TAG, "Peer Discovered");
        }
    }else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
        // Respond to new connection or disconnections
    }else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
        // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
    }
}
}
```

```
public class WDDiscovery {

    WifiP2pManager mManager;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    public WDDiscovery(WifiP2pManager manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel channel) {
        mManager = manager;
        mChannel = channel;
    }

    public void discover() {

        mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.i(TAG, "WiFi P2P Discovery successful");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                Log.i(TAG, "WiFi P2P Discovery error");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What are you using as your `ListView`/`Adapter`? I see no code relating to  a `ListView`here.

Comment: I'm not using adapter yet. WifiP2pManager calls public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList){ but peerList is empty

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint at the call of the callback. See what values you are getting for the peerList before, during, and after the call.

Comment: There is some useful information here I think may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729814/wifi-direct-on-android-not-working-properly

Comment: I did, and the "solution" is exactly what I'm doing, but List of peers is always empty despite of the BroadcastListener detects peers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79713/discussion-between-protectedvoid-and-tukajo).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I add

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

in manifest and give app the permission.
It works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, the solution in my case was

add these two lines into Android Manifiest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

and make sure to ask for runtime permission of the location